# A Fourier cosine series of type $f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(2^k x)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For a function $f(x)$ defined on $x \in [0,\pi]$, one can write $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(kx)$$
for some coefficients $a_k$. Fourier claimed that any function $f(x)$ can be expanded in terms of cosines in this way, where
$$a_k=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \cos(kx) dx.$$
Are there similar results for a different cosine series, as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(2^{k}x)$?

Comment: Cosines are not enough, you also need sines. And all of them, so you can't restrict to $k=2^n$.

Comment: @Blezej : $\{ 1,\cos(x),\cos(2x),\cdots\}$ is a complete orthogonal basis of $L^{2}[0,\pi]$. Similarly, $\{ \sin(x),\sin(2x),\sin(3x),\cdots\}$ is a complete orthogonal basis of $L^{2}[0,\pi]$. Pointwise convergence at the endpoints is a separate issue, and does not affect the $L^{2}$ convergence, or the interior pointwise convergence.

Comment: If you have an orthonormal basis $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3,\cdots \}$, then no subset of this basis can be an orthonormal basis. So the answer to your question is, "No." There are other numbers $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_n \cdots$, other than $0 < 1 < 2 < \cdots$ that will result in an orthogonal basis of cosines on $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @TrialAndError, thank you!